# Incrementing date in angular template

Tags: html, angular, date

I have something like below and i need to display dates incrementally

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
      <h2>
       {{item.name}}
      </h2>
      <p >
        {{item.description}}
      </p>
      <time>{{date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</time>
  </li>
</ul>
```

dates need to be shown as for first item it shows today's date and then tomorrow and so on.
If there is a way that it can be done only by using html template then its better. Or just help with the best way to do this.

Comment: can you explain a little more what this is displaying and what you're expecting it to display, plus an example of what your `items` array looks like? Also, you don't need to to use the `<time>` tag when using the date pipe. you can use a div or span.

Comment: solution does not have anything to do with items array it is there just maybe if index needs to be used

Comment: main question is regarding showing dates for first item today's date, then for second item tomorrow's date and so on

Comment: gotcha. I missed that `date` was not `item.date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this with only the date pipe, its primary use is morphing a current date into a different display. Not adding/removing. Something you could do is create your own date pipe that has an offset option

### Solution 1

Creating a new pipe and using the moment library

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({name: 'customDate'})
export class CustomDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(date, format = 'dd/MM/yyyy', dayOffset = 0, monthOffset = 0, yearOffset = 0) {
    return moment(new Date(date)).add(dayOffset, 'days')
                                 .add(monthOffset, 'months')
                                 .add(yearOffset, 'years')
                                 .format(format);
  }
}
```

and then reference it in html as this

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
      <span>{{date | customDate: 'dd/MM/yyyy': i}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Solution 2

Or you can use vanilla javascript Date along with a custom pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'customDate'})
export class CustomDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(date, format = 'dd/MM/yyyy', dayOffset = 0) {
    return new Date(date).addDays(dayOffset);
  }
}
```

and reference it like this

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
      <span>{{date | customDate: i | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this really the best way, why is this better then me just calling a function which returns the incremented date.

Comment: because that function will fire on every digest cycle. a pipe will check if anything has changed, and if it doesn't it doesn't fire any logic. you can double check this with a console.log() in a function added to the html vs a pipe

Comment: @Nnnnn here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybNj-id0kjY) explaining how pipes optimize programs. I would jump to 25 minutes.